# PHP - How to display the contents of an address that contains an array

Tags: php, arrays, class

How do you display the contents of an address that contains an array?

Example:

```
class ConferenceInfo {

    var $confID;
    var $confName;
    var $divisons = array(); 

    /* display an address in HTML */
    function display() {
        $output = '';
        $output .= $this->confID;
        $output .= $this->confName;
        foreach($this->divisons as $value) { // I know this is incorrect
            $output .= $value;          
        }
        $output .= '<br/>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

And the PHP code:

```
$conf = new ConferenceInfo;
$conf->confID = $someValue1;
$conf->confName = $someValue2;
$conf->divisons[] = $someValue3;   // this will eventually loop and fill in multiple values
echo $conf->display();
```

Data examples would be:

```
confID = 1<br/>
confName = Eastern<br/>
dvisions = Atlantic, Central, Northeast
```

Expected output from `display()` would be:

```
1EasternAtlanticCentralNortheast
```

Comment: What's wrong with the loop?

Comment: Theres no echo, so nothing shows on screen

Comment: Try some PHP-debugging with `var_dump` inside `display()` before the loop, within the loop, after the loop etc. Then you can see what values there really are and if it is iterated etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ConferenceInfo {

    var $confID;
    var $confName;
    var $divisons = array(); 

    /* display an address in HTML */
    function display() {
        $output = '';
        $output .= $this->confID;
        $output .= $this->confName;
        foreach($this->divisons as $value) {
            $output .= $value; 
        }
        $output .= '<br/>';
        return $output;
    }
}

$conf = new ConferenceInfo;
$conf->confID = 1;
$conf->confName = "Eastern";
$conf->divisons = array("Atlantic", "Central", "Northeast");
echo $conf->display();
```

Comment: My bad. The echo was left off in my post. I do have it as you describe. echo $conf->display(); I fixed the post.

Comment: Another bad on my part. I did have []. It's also an array from another class. Geez. I'm going to remove this post, start over, and get my %$#@ together.